# Return to a specific value in a column, associated with the maximum value in a row

Tags: excel

i'm working with excel, and i'm trying to Fill a column (Column E), with the associated value, where the maximum value of a row exists. as an illustration, Within Row 2(B2, C2, and D2), the maximum value is 7. 7 is exists in Column D, and associated with number 3, thus, the result should be 3.

ABCDE

1 1230

2   0173
3   0532

4   4710

what function should I use and how's the syntax looks like ?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Hi Martin, thanks for clarifying, i'm unable to attach image from excel snapshot since my points is not sufficient. Anyway, E3 contains 2 - That is because within row 3 the maximum number is 5 ; and 5 is within column C - with associated number 2. Do I make myself clear enough ?

Comment: That way, I need a formula to automatically link the maximum number within a row, with a number associated with the column where that maximum number exist.